# Is it a good practice to rely on garbage collector in PHP?

Tags: php

I have two methods:

```
public function a()
{
    $db = new Database();
    $db->query ('....');
    // $db->close();
}

public function b()
{
    $db = new Database();
    $db->query ('....');
    // $db->close();
}
```

they called in order:

```
$obj->a();
$obj->b();
```

I intentionally commented the `close()` methods. This `Database` class has a destruct method:

```
class Database
{
    public function __destruct()
    {
        $this->close();
    }

    public function close()
    {
    }
}
```

I want automatic close database connections between method calls. To do so, the 100% sure way is to call the `Database::close` method, but I want to do it automatic and be done when method its over. Is this safe way? Because I dont know when garbage collector actually deletes that $`db` object. What if its still exits when `b()` runs? Theoretically, garbage collector do the cleaning ups when he feels like...

**EDIT**

the database closing is just an example! I want to do something else, but this was a good example, dont focus on the closing itself!!

Comment: "*I want automatic close database connections between method calls.*" What? Just so you can keep opening the connection, logging in, etc.? Why are you treating your DB connection like a REST interface?

Comment: Please read the PHP manual on [variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: Maybe the really important question here is why? What are you trying to achieve? Security? If so, you obviously misunderstood something.

Comment: I edited the question, DB closing was just an example

Comment: Still, no idea of what you actually are trying to do, so you can't really get a useful answer.

Comment: "what if `$db` still exists when b() runs?" 1) it couldn't exist because it's not declared globally 2) if it existed (magic sometimes happens, but usually not in PHP), it would be overwritten by `$db = new Database()`

Comment: yea, but Im not sure the destructor() is called right away. Because garbage collector can call it 5 seconds later

Comment: I will rather ask it on another way, it seems that everybody stick on the database close-open itself...

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to close DB connections after each method call.

Usually people create and keep one connection for all script lifetime.

Of course,I assume there is one DB in your project.

You idea is a bad design example. I would recommend you to review you architecture design.

Comment: What Bogdan said.  You should recycle your same connection per php session unless you require multiple sessions -- very rare.  After all database stuff is done, then yes, close the connection, and free the variable.  PHP's garbage collection is pretty good, however it's there more for memory leaks -- not poor/lazy programming.

Comment: Very true. I edited the question, DB closing was just an example

Comment: Let me post my reply regarding when one should destroy and free the memory of an object manually. Posting as an answer due to the length.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you generally should not close/destroy an object that is reusable until you are finished with it completely, although there are some exceptions.

If you know that you will be calling the process multiple times, then you should not destroy the object until after the last call has been made. An exception to this would be if inside the object, you are working with another object or large amounts of data which need to be forcibly free'd on completion of each loop, then you should destroy only that object which is consuming or potentially consuming a large amount of resources once you have finished that cycle.

As far as the `__destruct()` function, you should put all the code in there needed to destroy the object. Calling another function from within that object is what we programmers call a cyclic reference where you have the memory of one space pointing back to itself and can cause the garbage collection to fail.

The highest level of control you have over freeing memory from within PHP is to use the unset() command on the object you wish to have destroyed.  Using `unset()` on an object pointer to a class will call that classes `__destruct()` function.

Executing `unset()` on an object tells the GAC to give a higher priority when resources are required to cleanup those objects referenced using that command. This is what makes this useful when using memory intensive loops, or poorly written classes within your objects.